# Updating Table from KDB+ to SQL Server using Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, kdb, pyq

I would like to have a table in SQL server update daily from a table that is already updated daily in KDB. I have connected ny SQL database to python and plan to do the same with the KDB database but I am not sure what my next step would be to have the KDB table update the SQL table.

Here is my code so far which successfully connects to the database

```
import pyodbc
db = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};'
    r'SERVER=serverName;'
    r'DATABASE=DBName;'
    r'UID=UN;'
    r'PWD=PW') 
cur = db.cursor()
SQLCommand = ("SELECT * "
               "FROM Table1") 
cur.execute(SQLCommand)
results = cur.fetchone() 
while results:
     results = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is an appropriate question. Seems like you really need to read up on the KDB+ documentation? There appears to be a relevant Python library (http://code.kx.com/wiki/Contrib/PyQ#PyQ:_Python_Integration). That would solve 'accessing' the KDB+ instance. Then you have to figure out the mappings from one database to the other, and that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

So while you *can* use Python as an intermediary here, why bother? You can instead use the ODBC driver natively in kdb+ as explained [here](http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/q-client-for-odbc/).

You'll need to write something to create your querystrings for insertion, selection etc., but this is pretty easily done.

If you really *must* use Python, [exxeleron's qpython package](http://github.com/exxeleron/qpython) is the easiest way for handling python <-> q IPC (you can use pyQ as above but if you're deadset on using Python then you probably only want a plug-in Python module).

```
\l odbc.k
odbcHandle: .odbc.open"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=serverName;DATABASE=DBName;UID=UN;PWD=PW";
makeCall: .odbc.eval[odbcHandle];
data: makeCall"SELECT * FROM tableName";
countQuery:"SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct FROM otherTable";
ct: first exec ct from makeCall countQuery;
makeCall"INSERT INTO otherTable (col1, col2) VALUES ('a', 'b');"; //you can also generate this string dynamically - this is an exercise for the reader
ct2: first exec ct from makeCall countQuery;
ct - ct2; // 1
.odbc.close odbcHandle
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [PyQ](https://pyq.enlnt.com), then fetching the data from kdb+ tables is trivial. Suppose you have a table called `t`:

```
>>> from pyq import q
>>> q.load(':/path/to/t')  # if t is not already loaded
>>> q.t.show()
a b
----
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
5 50
```

To convert this data to a list of tuples that can be sent over PyODBC, simply iterate over the table in a list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [tuple(row.value) for row in q.t]
>>> data
[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 40), (5, 50)]
```

This list can be sent the SQL server using the `executemany` method:

```
cur.executemany("insert into t(a, b) values (?, ?)", data)
```